# Amazon S3 GetObjectMetadata failed (The underlying connection was closed)?

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon WS SDK for .net and trying to get S3ObjectMetaData Info and in return what i got is an exception below. Seems like the AmazonS3Client connection get closed or timeout, I am not sure about the cause.

How can i fix this error. Is there any way i can check if S3Client is no more valid and need to recreate its instance?

Regards.

Stack Trace:
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.ProcessRequestError(HttpWebRequest request, WebException we, HttpWebResponse errorResponse, String requestAddr, WebHeaderCollection& respHdrs, Type t)
   at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.Invoke[T](S3Request userRequest)
   at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.GetObjectMetadata(GetObjectMetadataRequest request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using https, and your bucket name has a '.' in it?

Try turning off HTTPS:

c.CommunicationProtocol = Protocol.HTTP;
 using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID,c))

Or if you want to keep HTTPS, remake your bucket with no '.' in the name

Comment: i don't have . in name of bucket. but i'll have to check if i am using HTTPS